# event.dataTransfer.files undefined in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding drag-drop functionality to a project of mine and I'm getting a problem with firefox.

My code that I'm testing this situation with is:

```
document.getElementById("folder_files").addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
   alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].fileName);
}, false);
```

To test, I'm dragging a file into my folder_files div.  In chrome (version 16) the alert pops up with the filename fine.  With firefox (version 8), I get undefined.  Any ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  After dumping everything in the object I could see that chrome was getting different data than firefox.

What chrome was getting:

```
'0' ...
        'size' => "30379"
        'lastModifiedDate' ...
        'fileSize' => "30379"
        'name' => "bg.png"
        'type' => "image/png"
        'webkitRelativePath' => ""
        'fileName' => "bg.png"
        'webkitSlice' => "function webkitSlice() { [native code] }"
    'length' => "1"
    'item' => "function item() { [native code] }"
```

What firefox was getting:

```
0' ...
        'size' => "30379"
        'type' => "image/png"
        'mozSlice' => "function mozSlice() {
    [native code]
}"
        'name' => "bg.png"
        'mozFullPath' => ""
    'length' => "1"
    'item' => "function item() {
    [native code]
}"
```

Instead of using fileName/fileSize/fileType in my code, I just started using name/size/type.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a normalize function like below to support both:

```
// File Normalization for Firefox support:
_normalizeFunction: function (file) {
    if (file.name === undefined && file.size === undefined) {
        file.name = file.fileName;
        file.size = file.fileSize;
    }
},
```